# pipe works on localhost but not on remote nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, youtube, stream, pipe

I'm trying to use ytdl-core module in order to download youtube audio to my local disk (some path on my computer).

I created an API to which I can call with the requested youtube url and the destination folder in which I want the file to be saved.

```
app.get('/api/downloadYoutubeVideo', function (req, res) {  
var videoUrl = req.query.videoUrl;  
var destDir = req.query.destDir;    

ytdl.getInfo(videoUrl, function(err, info){
        var videoName = info.title.replace('|','').toString('ascii');       

        var stream = ytdl(videoUrl, { filter: 'audioonly'})
                       .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(destDir + '\\' + videoName + '.mp3'));

        stream.on('finish', function() {
            res.writeHead(204);
            res.end();
        });             
    });         
});
```

The problem is that when I call the api on my localhost (example: localhost:11245/api/downloadYoutubeVideo?videoUrl=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E5kJDWQSBUk&destDir=C:\test)
it works and the file indeed downloads to "C:\test".

But when I call to the api on my remote (example: http://sometest.cloudno.de/api/downloadYoutubeVideo?videoUrl=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=02BAlrAkuCE&destDir=C:\test)

**it doesnt create the file in the directory...**

I have searched the answer but haven't found one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does `C:\test` already exist on your remote? If not you can't use `fs.createWriteStream()` until the directory has been created, it will not create the directory for you implicitly. Since you're not listening for an `'error'` event, you wouldn't even know that was the problem since you're not capturing it.

The below code sample will check for the existence of `destDir` and if it doesn't exist will create it before proceeding.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const sep = require('path').sep;

function checkAndMakeDir(dir, cb) {
  fs.access(dir, (err) => {
    if (err)
      fs.mkdir(dir, (err) => {
        if (err)
          return cb(err);

        return cb();
      });
    else
      return cb();
  });
}

app.get('/api/downloadYoutubeVideo', function (req, res) {
  let videoUrl = req.query.videoUrl;
  let destDir = req.query.destDir;

  checkAndMakeDir(destDir, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(500);
      return res.end();
    }

    ytdl.getInfo(videoUrl, function (err, info) {
      let videoName = info.title.replace('|', '').toString('ascii');
      let saveStream = fs.createWriteStream(`${destDir}${sep}${videoName}.mp3`);

      saveStream.once('error', (err) => {
        console.log(err);
        res.writeHead(500);

        return res.end();
      });

      saveStream.once('finish', () => {
        res.writeHead(204);
        return res.end();
      });

      ytdl(videoUrl, {filter: 'audioonly'})
        .once('error', (err) => {
          console.log('Read Stream Error', err);

          res.writeHead(500);
          return res.end();
        })
        .pipe(saveStream);
    });
  });
});
```